# How to open HTTP(S) links which are part of a webpage in Firefox or Chrome in the macOS default browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, web-browser, defaults

Say my default browser on macOS is *Safari* and I am viewing a webpage in *Firefox* or *Chrome*. When I click on a HTTP(S) link on the webpage it opens again in the same application (*Firefox* or *Chrome*), *not* in the default browser (*Safari*).

Is there anyway to change this behaviour, so that links in a webpage open always in the default browser? (And if *Firefox* or *Chrome* can't do this, is there another browser which can?)

---

Note: I am on macOS Mojave, but I don't think this is a OS-level setting.

Comment: You can't configure Firefox or Chrome to do that. The default browser setting is used when clicking a link in an app that doesn't natively support the https:// and http:// schemes, like the Mail app. But since Firefox and Chrome support opening web links, they will load the pages themselves instead of using the default browser.

Comment: @jaume That’s what I feared… But it would be cool, if with a little switcher program like [Choosey](https://www.choosyosx.com/) or [brosel](https://github.com/halloleo/brosel), _every_ clicked link could be customised where it goes!

Comment: Yes, that's the way macOS is designed... I've added my comment as an answer in case you want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure Firefox or Chrome to do that.

The default browser setting is used when [clicking a link in an app that doesn't natively support the `https://` and `http://` schemes](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/make-safari-your-default-web-browser-ibrwa008/mac), like the Mail app. But since Firefox and Chrome support opening web links, they will load the pages themselves instead of using the default browser.