# Is there a method to have all links from a Chromium PWA application open in my default browser, Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, javascript, javascript-automation, chrome-extensions

### Problem Statement

On macOS, Is there a way to open all links from a Chromium PWA application in my default browser, Safari? Any advice or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

### Scenario

1. Open Bing Chat Microsoft Edge's PWA application
2. Any link clicked to be opened in Safari application instead of Microsoft Edge

### Attempted Solutions

I tried using **Choosy**, **Valjar**, and **Open In**. The only one that works but needs two clicks instead of one is **Choosy**, by right-clicking the link and pressing open in Choosy context menu. I thought of using Choosy API to prepend all links with Choosy using Tampermonkey user script. But I still cannot find a solid solution for my problem.

### Similar Threads/Posts

[Mac OS - Open links from Chrome PWAs in default browser instead (Safari)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448871/mac-os-open-links-from-chrome-pwas-in-default-browser-instead-safari) - No responses.

[How to open HTTP(S) links which are part of a webpage in Firefox or Chrome in the macOS default browser?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426786/how-to-open-https-links-which-are-part-of-a-webpage-in-firefox-or-chrome-in-th) - Outdated, no-mention of chromium userscripts/tampermonkey with choosy API.